# Trigger to handle bulk records

Tags: trigger

I wrote this trigger to change the lead owner to the user on the zip code custom object  record whenever the postal code on the lead has the postal code that matches an entry for the custom object zip code ,  Basically it the trigger checks the value of postal code on the lead record and if it is not null then it changes the lead owner to the owner of the zip code record , Zip code object has a custom user field ,

This code is working perfectly for small amount of records but when I am updating large no of records via dataloader this code give too many soql 101 errors.

I guess it need to be bulkified. could anyone please guide me with the correct problem and fixing that. Below is the code -

```
Trigger Changeleadowner on Lead (before insert, before update)
{List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
  if (l.PostalCode != NULL)   
      {// Find the sales rep for the current zipcode
       List<Zip_Codes__c> zip = [select user__c from Zip_codes__c where
 Name = :lead.PostalCode limit 1];     

          // if you found one
          if (zip.size() > 0)x
          {   //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
              lead.OwnerId = zip[0].User__c;leadsToUpdate.add(lead);

          }
       }
    }
}
```

Below is the code that i am trying to bulkify

```
trigger Changeowneronlead on Lead (before insert, before update) {


    Set<id> leadpostalcode = new Set<id>();
    for (lead a : Trigger.new)
    {if (a.PostalCode != NULL)
        leadpostalcode.add(a.postalcode); }  

     Map<string, zip_codes__c> zipcodes = new Map<string, zip_codes__c>([select user__c  from Zip_codes__c Where name IN :leadpostalcode]);  

    // iterate over the list of records being processed in the trigger and
    // set the color before being inserted or updated
    for (Lead a : Trigger.new)
        a.ownerid= zipcodes.get(a.OwnerId).User__c;

}
```

With the above code i am running into the below error :

> unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AddOwnerColor:
>   execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid
>   id: 12345: External entry point

could anyone please guide me with the correct problem and fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make practice to use collection to avoid queries in for loop. You have query in for loop:-
 `List<Zip_Codes__c> zip = [select user__c from Zip_codes__c where
 Name = :lead.PostalCode limit 1];`

Instead you can create collection and use as:

```
List<Lead> leadsToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
Set<String> postalCodes = new Set<String>();

for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
{
   if(l.PostalCode != null)
       postalCodes.add(l.PostalCode);
}

Map<String,Id> postalUserMap = new Map<String,Id>();
for(Zip_Codes__c zip = [SELECT Name, User__c from Zip_codes__c 
                        WHERE Name IN: postalCodes];     
{
       // Create Map to use
       postalUserMap.put(zip.Name, zip.User__c)
}

for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
{
      if (l.PostalCode != NULL)   
      {
         // Find the sales rep for the current zipcode
         // if you found one
         if (postalCodes.contains(l.PostalCode))
         {    
              //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
              // get owner from Map
              lead.OwnerId = postalUserMap.get(l.PostalCode);
              leadsToUpdate.add(lead);
         }
}
```

> Above example is for direction only but would work as well but not
>   tested. Same way you can resolve other issues and avoid SOQL query
>   using collections. Use appropriate checks to avoid other errors.

`System.StringException` is because you are assigning a number/text value to a field which is a LookUp type field.

Comment: Thank you Ashwani for the detailed response , Thank you very much :)

Comment: While testing the code i see Invalid type: postalUserMap , i am not sure what that means . Below is the code i tweaked :                                        for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
{
   if(l.PostalCode != null)
       postalCodes.add(l.PostalCode);
}

Map<String,Id> postalUserMap = new postalUser<String,Id>();
for(Zip_Codes__c zip : [SELECT Name, User__c from Zip_codes__c WHERE Name IN: postalCodes])   
{
       // Create Map to use
       postalUserMap.put(zip.Name, zip.User__c);
}

This returns the error  Invalid type: postalUser at line 11 column 36

Comment: @Natasha because there is type `postalUserMap<String,Id>();` should be `Map<String,Id>();`. That's all. I would recommend to understand the approach we used, instead of just copying code.

Comment: This works like a charm , I was able to perform a bulk insert , Thank you ever so much Ashwani , Also i am pretty new to coding , trying to grasp the concepts slowly .

Comment: Much appreciate your help on this one . Thanks a ton !

Comment: Done ! It is very much resolved ,